# Send email using Bamboo

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, digital-ocean, mail-server

I have used DigitalOcean to create a droplet, which I want to use as my mail server. I'm using PuTTY to access it. I've installed `postfix` and `mailutils` packages to send emails. When I use the following command to send emails, it works fine:-

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" your_email_address
```

However when I try to use the Elixir package Bamboo with the BambooSMTP adapter to send emails, I get the following error:-

```
** (Bamboo.SMTPAdapter.SMTPError) There was a problem sending the email through SMTP.

The error is :retries_exceeded

More detail below:

{:network_failure, '<ip-address>', {:error, :econnrefused}}

    (bamboo_smtp) lib/bamboo/adapters/smtp_adapter.ex:80: Bamboo.SMTPAdapter.handle_response/1
    (bamboo) lib/bamboo/mailer.ex:123: Bamboo.Mailer.deliver_now/3
```

This is my `config.exs` file:-

```
config :bamboo_email_smtp, BambooEmailSmtp.Mailer,
  adapter: Bamboo.SMTPAdapter,
  server: "<ip-address>",
  hostname: "<name of my droplet; it is also what I get when I type 'hostname' at the prompt>",
  port: 1025,
  username: "root", # or {:system, "SMTP_USERNAME"}
  password: "<the password I use to login to my droplet>", # or {:system, "SMTP_PASSWORD"}
  tls: :if_available, # can be `:always` or `:never`
  allowed_tls_versions: [:"tlsv1", :"tlsv1.1", :"tlsv1.2"], # or {":system", ALLOWED_TLS_VERSIONS"} w/ comma seprated values (e.g. "tlsv1.1,tlsv1.2")
  ssl: false, # can be `true`
  retries: 1,
  no_mx_lookups: false # can be `true`
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: Did you mean to use the Sendmail adapter instead of SMTP?

Comment: No, I meant to use the SMTP adapter.

Comment: Do you have the required ports open on the postfix box?

Comment: Well, I found out that Postfix uses port 25, so I changed the port in my Bamboo `config.exs` too. But I'm still getting the error.  However, instead of `:econnrefused`, it's `:timeout`.

Comment: Sorry old thread. But it is possible that your settings don’t allow external connections and you’d have enable it.